# Xamarin forms iOS apply same font but different style

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, google-font-api, roboto

I have a xamarin forms app. I want to make use of [Roboto Font Family](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto), from Google Fonts. Actually, Roboto Light and Roboto Regular. What's the name for Roboto Light and Roboto Regular for iOS?

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="RobotoLightFontFamily" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
    <On Platform="UWP" Value="/Assets/Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf#Roboto" />
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="Roboto Light" />
    <On Platform="Android" Value="Roboto-Light.ttf#Roboto" />
</OnPlatform>
<OnPlatform x:Key="RobotoRegularFontFamily" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
    <On Platform="UWP" Value="/Assets/Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf#Roboto" />
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="Roboto" />
    <On Platform="Android" Value="Roboto-Regular.ttf#Roboto" />
</OnPlatform>
```

It does not work like this... It only applies one font instead of both when using each font family foreach component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries, naming it Roboto-Light works.